# str.decode() does not work for Chinese characters in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, decode, encode

```
test_decode = '测试'
print test_decode.decode('utf-8')
```

The simple code above can work in local, but can not work when runs in pyspark, anyone know why? The error in pyspark is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/litaotao/Program/TrajectoryPrediction/src/cluster/Tool.py", line 62, in <module>
    print test_decode.decode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0):

add the code:

```
# coding=utf-8
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```